# How to dynamically insert closing tags in xml file if not present using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

For example

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
```

In the above xml `</note>` is missed, how to find and add the missed close tag dynamically in xml using nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse and validate XML, a [schema definition (XSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) is required.

With this, the parser is able to validate the elements and tell you if any are invalid - missing, spelled incorrectly etc.

Take your example - without an XSD, you won't know if `note` can contain any additional child elements such as `date` for example.

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<date>2016-01-01</date>
```

Whereas with as XSD, the parser will know that a `note` element will contain `to`, `from`, `heading` and `body` elements, after which it will expect a closing `note` tag.

Once you know where your validation issues are - for example a missing closing tag - you can perform your cleanup.

There are many XML parser options for NodeJS such as...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jgexml

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some parser which will parse the input dirty HTML and sanitize it.
You can feed DOMPurify with string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string with clean HTML.
Check this out https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

```
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyHTML);
```

The demo site https://cure53.de/purify

You can also explore [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and other similar DOM parser libraries.

Comment: DOMPurify looks more for protecting against XSS? Also don't see XML mentioned anywhere. Have you used it successfully with XML before?

Comment: @timothyclifford you r right. The solution which I have given will only work for HTML.

Comment: Might still be useful for the OP, never know :)